# Notation for isometric spaces?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, notation

Metric spaces are *isometric* if there exists a bijective isometry between them.

Is there a standard notation for this, along the same lines as $X\approx Y$ for homeomorphic spaces and $X\simeq Y$ for homotopy equivalent spaces?

Comment: I would say no. And actually I'm not sure that your notations for homeomorphism and homotopy equivalence, are completely standard...

Comment: In every case you can write $\cong$ when the *category* is clear in the context.

Comment: @Alain: point taken. I meant to say that the above symbols are standard enough that a topologist would know what they mean without them being defined. I was wondering if there was a similar symbol for isometry ($=$ seems inaccurate, and $\cong$ seems too general).

Comment: I don't know of such a notation. But I agree with Martin that if you scrupulously bear in mind the category under discussion, then $\cong$ is all-purpose. If that doesn't seem satisfactory, then I'd lamely offer $\cong_{\text{isom}}$ or something like that for emphasis. 